# hide future date in query builder datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery-query-builder

I would like to hide future date in datepicker(jquery query builder),if I set `maxDate: '0'`,future date are shown

```
{
    id: 'created_date',
    label: 'Date',
    type: 'datetime',
    validation: {
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
    },
    plugin: 'datepicker',
    plugin_config: {
        format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
        maxDate: 0,
        autoclose: true

    },
    operators: ['equal', 'not_equal', 'less', 'less_or_equal', 'greater', 'greater_or_equal', 'between', 'not_between', 'is_null', 'is_not_null']
},
```

How can I hide future date in query builder?

Comment: Future date are shown but can't be selected. So what's the problem ?

Comment: For this question you found lots of solution please at-least try to resolve your self. Stack overflow is not for the quick solution without making any afforts.

Comment: We used jquery datepicker

Answer (score 1):

Set `maxDate` as today's date, by using `new Date()`, or setting `maxDate` to 0 will disable the dates after todays date.

If you specifically want to hide the date, Add the following CSS 
`.ui-state-disabled{ visibility:hidden; }`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ay100070/

Comment: @rangas added Fiddle with example to hide the disabled dates.

Comment: @Ashish Don't give solution such kind of people who have not even find this kind of easy solution from internet. this is common usage and anyone can very easily find the solution. We are not here to give quick solution of this kind stuff or helping out of them.

Comment: @YagnikDetroja, "We are not here to give quick solution of this kind stuff or helping out of them." this is exactly why stackoverflow is,  I did what I had to do, now keep this "People should do things themselves because everyone is as smart as I am and they shouldn't ask for help" to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
        id: 'created_date',
        label: 'Date',
        type: 'datetime',
        validation: {
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
        },
        plugin: 'datepicker',
        plugin_config: {
            format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
             max:new Date(),
            autoclose: true

        },
        operators: ['equal', 'not_equal', 'less', 'less_or_equal', 'greater', 'greater_or_equal', 'between', 'not_between', 'is_null', 'is_not_null']
    },
```